# Anorm (Scala) query with json object (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

I'm trying to write this sql query with Anorm(Postgres):

`SELECT * FROM employee  WHERE id = 1
AND length(ee_json #>> '{path1,paht2}') BETWEEN  0 and 1;`

It should be something like this:

```
 SQL(
 s"""
  |SELECT id FROM employee  WHERE id = {id}
  |AND length(ee_json #>> {param} ) BETWEEN  {min} and {max}
  """.stripMargin)
  .on('id -> id,
  'min -> min,
  'max -> max,
  'param -> "'{path1,path2}'")
  .as(parser.*)
```

but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I run it.

Comment: Create table statement, example data and expected results?

Comment: employee table contains id(text) and ee_json which is jsonb. path1 and path2 are paths inside the json where the data of path2 is string.

Comment: W/o more context, at least the extra `'` in the value for the parameter `param` are not valid (as JDBC is also quoting string parameters).